# Rigorously showing supremum and infimum of a set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Given the set $A=\{\sin(\theta)|\theta \in ]0,\pi[\}$

It's quite easy to see that $\inf(A)=0$ and $\sup(A)=1$, and that $\inf(A)\notin A$ and $\sup(A) \in A$. However I'm unsure how one can show this rigorously.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a Taylor series?

Comment: Great tip, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\forall \theta \in]0,\pi [$$
$$0< \sin(\theta)\leq1$$

since $1=\sin (\frac {\pi}{2}) $ we can say
$$\sup A=1 \in A $$
$1$ is the greatest element of $A $.

on the other hand

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sin(\pi-\frac {1}{n})=0$$
we can say that
$$\inf A=0$$.